# Bank Statements and the Standard Visitor Visa

Tags: visas, uk, uk-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds, bolivia

I am applying for a visa for my son, not for myself. I am a British citizen, whilst my son is Bolivian. I work as a missionary with special needs kids, and my income is not a lot. It's adequate for Bolivia (more than, actually) but low for the UK.

My bank statements aren't great, we've been living off savings for the past year. Additionally, there's a lot of robbery here, so I put all my money into a savings account that can't be access offline, and transfer it only when necessary. So when I get income, I pull it out of the account immediately and put it in savings. But there is obviously also a lot coming out of savings. I do it for safety reasons, but it doesn't look good when I'm trying to prove financial stability.

I also have an account with the mission here in Bolivia (and it is a registered charity in the UK) which looks way better financially, because only my rent comes out of it and it's built up a considerable amount of money over the past year. However, it's not a bank account, just an account with the mission.

So my question is, do I send my own bank accounts? Or do I have my mum, his grandmother, sponsor his visit? We will both be living with her, and she's happy to do so. But I on my other post it was suggested that the application is stronger if it isn't sponsored.

And if I were to send my own bank statements, would it help his case to state that I intend to work while in the UK? I am a registered teacher in Northern Ireland and I am registered to substitute teach.

Comment: You may wish to check whether your son is a [British citizen by descent](https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen) and whether Bolivia allows dual citizenship.  If so, he can obtain a British passport instead of a visa.

Comment: I can apply for his citizenship, but it's a 9 month process and we would like to travel before that.

Comment: You can also attach your account with the mission. Although it is not a bank statement it provides a snapshot of your finances. I don’t think it is helpful to mention you will work in the UK. That usually implies building a life there, then suddenly they think what If she decides to stay, not a good look.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen okay, yeah that makes sense. and yeah, it also shows I am leaving money here in Bolivia, so I feel like that'll help? lol.

Comment: If your child is [automatically a British citizen](https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-british-parent/born-on-or-after-1-july-2006) then you can skip directly to [applying for his passport](https://www.gov.uk/get-a-child-passport/first-child-passport). The nine month £1012 process is not required in that case.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, do I send my own bank accounts?

Yes. I think you should use your own statement. It will be a lot stronger application if the child is funded by his parents than anyone else. Even though the balances may be small, it doesn’t cost much to take care of a child living with his grandparents. In my estimation even if you have £1000 or £1500 in your account it is sufficient. What is critical is you must include a cover letter explaining things. An adopted child going to visit his British grandparents accompanied by his adoptive British mother. Make it clear this is a visit. No mention of applying for citizenship for him later etc. Make it clear at this time Bolivia is your home and remains your home for the foreseeable future.

> Or do I have my mum, his grandmother, sponsor his visit?

No. See above.

> And if I were to send my own bank statements, would it help his case
>   to state that I intend to work while in the UK?

I don’t think it is helpful to mention you will work in the UK. That usually implies building a life there, then suddenly they think *what if she decides to stay*. Not a good look.